# Random Variables by Definition Independent of themselves?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

If we look at the definition of independence for discrete random variables:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
   \P(X \mid Y) = \P(X) 
$$ iff $X,Y$ independent.

isn't this then true for any random variable itself, i.e.:
$$
\P(X \mid X ) = \P(X)?  
$$

Comment: The probability that I roll a six if I roll a six is $1$, not $\frac16$.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so that
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
   \P(X=x,Y=y) = \P(X=x)\P(Y=y)
$$
So, if $X$ is independent of itself, then
$$
\P(X=x)=\P(X=x,X=x)= \\
\P(X=x)\P(X=x)=\P(X=x)^2
$$
Solving the equation $\P(X=x)=\P(X=x)^2$ gives
$\P(X=x)= 0 ~\text{or}~ =1$
So $X$ is a constant random variable. (That is, constant with probability one).

Comment: Thanks. That it is a constant follows from the fact that the realization "x" has probability 1 (and hence no other realization is possible), right? Does that mean then that a RV is only independent of itself iff it has only one realization (ie one value it can take on)?

Comment: It can well (in principle) take on multiple values, but all but one of those values will have probability zero.